# Codeigniter send email when website have a bug

Tags: php, codeigniter

When my website have a bug in production, result only can show in logs directory. Can the system send email automatically when my system have a bug?

I already create a class in libraries like this

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)

{   
    if (ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
        $ci =& get_instance();

        $ci->load->library('email');
        $ci->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $ci->email->to('someone@example.com');
        $ci->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
        $ci->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');
        $ci->email->subject('error');
        $ci->email->message('Severity: '.$severity.'  --> '.$message. ' '.$filepath.' '.$line);
        $ci->email->send();
    }


    parent::log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
}
```

}

but it still not working

Comment: try to use `set_error_handler()`

Comment: You can extend the exception class
[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260655/4799571)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In CodeIgniter, How Can I Have PHP Error Messages Emailed to Me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260597/in-codeigniter-how-can-i-have-php-error-messages-emailed-to-me)

Comment: email can't be send. shoud I config protocol, host, ect? @AbhinK

Answer (score 0):

I put in application/core, not in application/libraries. And it's working